# Drag and Drop between Instances of the same application. (GtkTreeView)

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, gtk, gtkmm, gtktreeview

I am trying to receive drag and drop content between instances of the same application from a GtkTreeView. The contents are pointers to objects and I couldn't manage to trigger the receive event on the target application treeview. I could only receive the drag content in the same treeview. Here is the code part:

```
...
vector<Gtk::TargetEntry> gtkTargetsDest, gtkTargetsSrc;
gtkTargetsDest.push_back(Gtk::TargetEntry(
  "SrcFile **pSrcFiles", Gtk::TargetFlags(0), 0));
gtkTargetsSrc.push_back(Gtk::TargetEntry(
   "SrcFile **pSrcFiles", Gtk::TargetFlags(0), 1));
_gtkTreeView.enable_model_drag_dest(gtkTargetsDest);
_gtkTreeView.enable_model_drag_source(gtkTargetsSrc);
...

void onGtkTreeViewDragDataReceived(
  const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext> &pGdkDragContext, int x, int y,
  const Gtk::SelectionData &gtkSelData, guint info, guint time)
{
  if (info == 0) {
    SrcFile** pSrcFiles
      = (SrcFile**)gtkSelData.get_data();
    while (*pSrcFiles) {
      _ptrMFieldRef->add(*pSrcFiles); // add dropped src files
      ++pSrcFiles;
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of `Gtk::TargetFlags(0)` I tried `Gtk::TARGET_OTHER_APP` but that didn't help at all. I got a hint that this could work with the clipboard, but I do have no idea how this should work, since the receive event is not triggered...

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop methods for GtkTreeview appear to be limited to dragging within the same tree widget. Use the regular gtk Drag and Drop between programs, for an example see
[Tutorial de GTK+ 2.0 TreeView](https://people.gnome.org/~csaavedra/documents/treeview-tutorial/sec-dnd.html)

To limit Drag and Drop to a specific application one can set/get the widget name, optionally using the PID in the string, something like "myapp.tree1-PID".